# ActiveRecord: find by associated objects value within range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: `Number` and `Range`

```
#  number   :integer
class Number < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ranges
end

#  first_id   :integer
#  last_id    :integer
class Range < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first, class_name: 'Number'
  belongs_to :last,  class_name: 'Number'
end
```

I have some entries in my database:

```
=>  [#Number: id: 1, number: 1]
=>  [#Number: id: 2, number: 7]
=>  [#Number: id: 3, number: 3]
=>  [#Number: id: 4, number: 42]
=>  [#Number: id: 5, number: 23]

=>  [#Range: id: 1, first_id: 1, last_id: 2]
```

The saved `Range` is associated with the first `Number` `1` and the last `Number` `7`, but it should be selected if I ask for the `Ranges` of `=>  [#Number: id: 3, number: 3]`, too.

How can I get all `Range` for a `Number` which is not the `first` or `last` of `Range`, but within the range?

I tried it with `.joins(:first, :last).where(['numbers.number <= ? ....` with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is as elegant as what you're seeking, but this doesn't necessarily need to be a relationship so much as a class method returning a query. With a method like this in your Range model, you could simply call Range.numbers and return the results you're seeking.

```
def numbers
    Number.where( number: first_id..last_id )
end
```

Alternatively, in Number.rb you could have a ranges method like so:

```
def ranges
    Range.where( 'first_id <= ? AND last_id >= ?', number, number )
end
```

Comment: Thank you. 'Range.where( 'first_id <= ? AND last_id >= ?', number, number )' would not return any `Range`, because it uses `id` instead of `number` in `where()`.